# Liferay CustomSQL table doesn't exist

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

I have a service entity declaration which is as follows:

```
<entity name="MyContentRepo" local-service="true" remote-service="true" table="contentrepo">
</entity>
```

I am trying to use Custom SQL to fetch some details:

```
session = openSession();
String sqlQueryString = CustomSQLUtil.get("query_id");
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQueryString);
query.addEntity("MyContentRepo", MyContentRepoImpl.class);
QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(query);
qPos.add("someparameter");
list = (List<MyContentRepo>) query.list();
```

But I get the following error upon execution:

```
08:02:26,640 ERROR [http-bio-8090-exec-72][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] Table 'mysqldb.mycontentrepo' doesn't exist
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

The query is taking the name of entity declared not the table="contentrepo". can anyone tell me how to bypass this issue?

Comment: As per https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addEntity%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29 you have to provide first argument in addEntity method as table alias. Try giving table name itself it should work

Answer (score 1):

AddEntity once the SQLQuery has been translated to QueryPos. Change your code as given below:

`session = openSession();`

`String sqlQueryString = CustomSQLUtil.get("query_id");
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQueryString);`

`QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(query);
qPos.add("someparameter");`

`query.addEntity("MyContentRepo", MyContentRepoImpl.class);
list = (List<MyContentRepo>) query.list();`